# how to register firebase-messaging-sw.js in vue app with env variable?

Tags: vuejs2, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

`let firebaseConfig = { apiKey: "DTfsawaSyDwR-WuG-fdsaewyr849243", authDomain: "notification-dev.firebaseapp.com", projectId: "notification-dev", storageBucket: "notification-dev.appspot.com", messagingSenderId: "43472143124234321169", appId: "1:421467348324:web:8f4e271c432dw4c3arw700" }`

is it safe to pass these variable directly in to service worker when registering firebase service worker

Right now values are directly hardcoded, is it fine or a vulnerablility.